# Meaning of CORBA No IMPLEMENT exception

Tags: websphere, corba

What is the meaning of this CORBA exception :

org.omg.CORBA.NO_IMPLEMENT: Retry limit reached  vmcid: 0x49421000  minor code: 40

I dont't have any other information in my log file.

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1):

This is a WebSphere specific minor code which is not mentioned in the CORBA specification. Check the IBM WebSphere website, there are several APAR referring to fixes for use cases when this exception does occur, for example [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PK28779) and [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PK20304)

Comment: Sounds like WebSphere should have used `IMP_LIMIT` instead for something like a retry limit being reached. Oh well, not the first ORB to use the wrong exception :)